# How to update hierarchical data in the same table

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, hierarchical

I have two tables. The first table contains some data changes by year and territory_id.

```
territory_id      year  count_sth
430000000         2015  130
431000000         2015  15
433200000         2015  75
433600000         2015  40
431000000         2014  13
433200000         2014  20
...
```

Second table contains relationship between territory_id in the form of parent-child.

```
territory_id      parent_id     desc_ru
430000000         0             'abc'
431000000         430000000     'sdf'    
433200000         430000000     'jkl'
433210000         433200000     'bnm'
...
```

I want to set the value of column `count_sth` (table1) as the sum of values of the childrens group by year. It should be updated automatically. Each time when we update `count_sth`, value of `count_sth` where `territory_id` is parent of some territory will be equal to sum of values `count_sth` of its childs.
How to do it?
I tried to use function returns trigger to update this (table1) table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table__byyear()
RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
  BEGIN

UPDATE table__byyear f
SET    count_sth= A.a1
    from (select b.year, b.sum(count_sth) as a1, t.parent_id
          from table__byyear b join admterr t
          on b.territory_id = t.territory_id 
             GROUP by b.year, t.parent_id) A
where f.territory_id = A.parent_id and f.year = A.year
AND   count_sth IS DISTINCT FROM A.a1;

RETURN NULL;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER table__byyear_terr
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table__byyear 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE table__byyear();
```

But here, this UPDATE trigger runs another UPDATE on the same table, which will fire the trigger again, so we get infinite recursion.
Point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following statement to update a row and all the parent rows at once:

```
with recursive hier as (
  -- a row
  select t.territory_id, 
         t.parent_id,
         b.year
  from   table__byyear b,
         admterr t
  where  t.territory_id = 433210000 --<< change me
  and    b.year = 2015              --<< change me
  and    t.territory_id = b.territory_id
  union all
  -- parent rows
  select t.territory_id,
         t.parent_id,
         prev.year
  from   hier prev,
         admterr t
  where  t.territory_id = prev.parent_id
)
update table__byyear
set    count_sth = count_sth + 100 --<< change me
where  (territory_id, year) in (select territory_id, year from hier);
```

Given this statement, you may want to create a function...

```
create function update_hier(
  territory_id integer,
  year integer,
  delta numeric
)
returns void
as $$
  with ...
  update table__byyear
  set    count_sth = count_sth + $3
  where  (territory_id, year) in (select territory_id, year from hier);
$$ language sql;
```

...and even create a view with instead-of-update trigger to call this function.